# if $\lim_{\to\infty}a_{+1}−_n=0$ then $\lim_{\to\infty}_{+1}^2−_^2=0$？

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

if $$\lim\limits_{→∞}_{+1}−_=0$$
Whether $$\lim\limits_{→∞}_{+1}^2-_^2=0$$
$\{a_n\}$ is not necessarily convergent

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n+1} + a_n\right)$ exists (and finite), then yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_n=n^s$ with $s>0$.  Then
$$a_{n+1}-a_n\to\begin{cases}0&\hbox{if $s<1$}\\1&\hbox{if $s=1$}\\ \infty&\hbox{if $s>1$.}\end{cases}$$
So if we choose $s$ between $\frac12$ and $1$ then we have
$$a_{n+1}-a_n\to0\quad\hbox{but}\quad a_{n+1}^2-a_{n\vphantom1}^2\to\infty\ .$$
The simplest example is $a_n=n^{1/2}=\sqrt n\,$, when $a_{n+1}-a_n\to0$ but $a_{n+1}^2-a_{n\vphantom1}^2\to1$.

Comment: It is against MSE's rules to answer questions without context. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1